# Trying to mimic Splitwise app logic - suggest a better way to handle settlements

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I am trying to write the basic logic used in apps like [Splitwise](https://www.splitwise.com/).

Input - Transactions in the trip

```
a|a,b,c,d|120
b|a,b,d|210
c|a,b,c,d|40
a|a,b,c|60
```

- `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are friends on a trip
- in the first transaction `a` paid 120 units for a transaction involving all four friends
- in the second transaction `b` paid 210 units for a transaction involving only `a`, `b` and `d`
- there are `n` such transactions and there can be `m` friends

Expected Output

```
a has to get 50
b has to get 80
c has to give 20
d has to give 110

d has to give 80 to b
d has to give 30 to a
c has to give 20 to a
```

This is what I tried. `Person` class is the pojo used.

```
public class Person {
 private String name;
 private Integer totalExpense;
 private Integer totalSpent;
 private Integer balanceAmt;
}
```

This is the code for settle operation.

```
public void settle(Map<String, Person> personMap) {
 List<Person> getterList = new ArrayList<>();
 List<Person> giversList = new ArrayList<>();

 for (String key : personMap.keySet()) {
  Person user = personMap.get(key);
  int balanceAmt = user.getTotalSpent() - user.getTotalExpense();
  user.setBalanceAmt(Math.abs(balanceAmt));

  if (balanceAmt > 0) {
   System.out.println(key + " has to get " + balanceAmt);
   getterList.add(user);
  } else if (balanceAmt < 0) {
   System.out.println(key + " has to give " + Math.abs(balanceAmt));
   giversList.add(user);
  } else if (balanceAmt == 0) {
   System.out.println(key + " is all settled");
  }
 }

 getterList.sort((p2, p1) -> p1.getBalanceAmt().compareTo(p2.getBalanceAmt()));
 giversList.sort((p2, p1) -> p1.getBalanceAmt().compareTo(p2.getBalanceAmt()));

 giversList.forEach(giver -> {
  getterList.forEach(getter -> {                
   if (getter.getBalanceAmt() == 0) {
    return;
   }
   if (giver.getBalanceAmt() == getter.getBalanceAmt()) {
    System.out.println(giver.getName() + " has to give " + giver.getBalanceAmt() + " to " + getter.getName());
    giver.setBalanceAmt(0);
    getter.setBalanceAmt(0);
   } else if (giver.getBalanceAmt() > getter.getBalanceAmt()) {
    System.out.println(giver.getName() + " has to give " + getter.getBalanceAmt() + " to " + getter.getName());
    giver.setBalanceAmt(giver.getBalanceAmt() - getter.getBalanceAmt());
    getter.setBalanceAmt(0); 
   } else if (giver.getBalanceAmt() < getter.getBalanceAmt()) {
    System.out.println(giver.getName() + " has to give " + giver.getBalanceAmt() + " to " + getter.getName());
    giver.setBalanceAmt(0);
    getter.setBalanceAmt(getter.getBalanceAmt() - giver.getBalanceAmt());
   }
  });
 });
}
```

The code is not good, it has too many loops.
Suggest a good method to settle the amount and come up with the second part of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your bottom part's logic from O(m<sup>2</sup>) to O(m) by using two pointer.

```
int giverPointer = 0;
int getterPointer = 0;
while(giverPointer < giversList.size() && getterPointer < getterList.size()){
    if (giversList.get(giverPointer).getBalanceAmt() == getterList.get(getterPointer).getBalanceAmt()) {
        System.out.println(giversList.get(giverPointer).getName() + " has to give " + giversList.get(giverPointer).getBalanceAmt() + " to " + getterList.get(getterPointer).getName());
        giversList.get(giverPointer).setBalanceAmt(0);
        getterList.get(getterPointer).setBalanceAmt(0);
        giverPointer++;
        getterPointer++;
    } else if (giversList.get(giverPointer).getBalanceAmt() > getterList.get(getterPointer).getBalanceAmt()) {
        System.out.println(giversList.get(giverPointer).getName() + " has to give " + getterList.get(getterPointer).getBalanceAmt() + " to " + getterList.get(getterPointer).getName());
        giversList.get(giverPointer).setBalanceAmt(giversList.get(giverPointer).getBalanceAmt() - getterList.get(getterPointer).getBalanceAmt());
        getterList.get(getterPointer).setBalanceAmt(0); 
        getterPointer++;
    } else {
        System.out.println(giversList.get(giverPointer).getName() + " has to give " + giversList.get(giverPointer).getBalanceAmt() + " to " + getterList.get(getterPointer).getName());
        giversList.get(giverPointer).setBalanceAmt(0);
        getterList.get(getterPointer).setBalanceAmt(getterList.get(getterPointer).getBalanceAmt() - giversList.get(giverPointer).getBalanceAmt());
        giverPointer++;
    }
}
```